# Custom Authorizer AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to attach a custom authorizer to API using CDK.

I am using Cognito for the user management.

What I want to achieve with the custom authorizer is,

- Check whether the user has permission to use the API
- Identify the user's email (userId) and attach it to the request body
- Use that email inside the API lambda

I can't find any examples or documents regarding how to attach a custom authorizer to an API. How can I attach an custom authorizer or if it's not supported in CDK is there a work around to achieve the requirements?

Comment: There are some clues here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/723

Answer (score 3):

The following may help you get what you want to achieve. Currently the `authorizer` on the `addMethod` isnt implemented so you need to override.

```
const api = new RestApi(this, 'RestAPI', {
    restApiName: 'Rest-Name',
    description: 'API for journey services.',
});

const putIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(handler);

const auth = new CfnAuthorizer(this, 'CustomAuthorizer', {
    name: 'custom-authorizer',
    type: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
    ...
});

const post = api.root.addMethod('PUT', putIntegration, { authorizationType: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM });
const postMethod = post.node.defaultChild as CfnMethod;
postMethod.addOverride('Properties.AuthorizerId', { Ref: auth.logicalId });
```

This attaches the created `authorizer`

Comment: Hey, there is an `authorizer` option on `addMethod` now:  

api.root.addMethod('PUT', putIntegration, {
  authorizationType: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
  authorizer: {
    authorizerId: authorizer.ref
  }
}

Answer (score -3):

To add on to the previous answer, as of 2021 there's `[CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer][1]` that you can use instead so you can use the following:

You should configure Cognito authorizer and attach to the API you created.

1. create authorizer
2. create API gateway, attach the cognito authorizer to the api
3. create resource and method
4. specify the integration proxy and authorizer

   ```
    const cognitoAuthorizer = new api.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'cognitoApiAuthorizer', {
      cognitoUserPools: [
        cognito.UserPool.fromUserPoolId(
          this,
          "existing-userpool",
          this.props.userPoolId,
        ),
      ],
    });

    const apiGateway = new api.RestApi(this, 'rest-api', {
      restApiName: 'assets-api',
      defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: api.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        authorizer: cognitoAuthorizer,
      }
    });
    const putIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(handler);
    const resourceA = apiGateway.root.addResource('resourceA');
    resourceA.addMethod('PUT', putIntegration, {
      authorizer: {
        authorizationType: api.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        authorizerId: cognitoAuthorizer.authorizerId,
      }
    });
   ```